# Cross function not working for time dependent variables

Tags: functions, cross

I have two 1x3 matrices both containing time derivatives:
OwC = {{a'[t]}, {b'[t]+c'[t]}, {0}}
EwB= {{0},{b'[t]},{0}}
But when I do Cross[OwC,EwB]
I get: Cross::nonn1: The arguments are expected to be vectors of equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inner curly brackets:

```
owc={a'[t],b'[t]+c'[t],0}
ewb={0,b'[t],0}

Cross[owc,ewb]
(* {0, 0, Derivative[1][a][t] Derivative[1][b][t]} *)
```